# Client side validation "required" with conditional logic to kendo DropDownList from the ASP.NET MVC UI Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC. I was wondering if there was a way to add conditional logic to the HtmlAttributes of a DropDownList using Razor. As you can see from my example

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.RequestedDate)
    .Name("RequestedDate")
    .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .Value(Model.DocumentId != null ? Model.RequestedDate : DateTime.Today)
 )
```

I am setting the value according to if my model has Id or not. I was wondering if there was a syntax for my question. Possibly something like that

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.RequestedDate)
    .Name("RequestedDate")
    .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" if(Model.DocumentId){ required = "required" })
    .Value(Model.DocumentId != null ? Model.RequestedDate : DateTime.Today)
 )
```

I know it can be done through javascript on the databound event possibly of the element but my question is if there is a way of doing this in my razor page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upvoted @ChrisC answer because he helped me see it the way I needed. The way I handled it is like that:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.RequestedDate)
    .Name("RequestedDate").Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
    .HtmlAttributes(Model.DocumentId == null ? (object) new { style = "width:100%" } : new { style = "width:100%", required = "required" })
     .Value(Model.DocumentId != null ? Model.RequestedDate : DateTime.Today)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Razor is essentially just C# running in the view. What you are trying to do here is wrapping an `if` statement within the bounds of an object i.e. it won't compile.

The best thing you can do is move the object value from the `HtmlAttributes` method out and splitting that with the `if` statement instead:

```
@{
object myAttributes = null;

    if(Model.DocumentId) {
        myAttributes = new { style = "width:100%", required = "required" }
    }
    else {
        myAttributes = new { style = "width:100%" }
    }
}
```

and then have

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.RequestedDate)
    .Name("RequestedDate")
    .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
    .HtmlAttributes(myAttributes)
    .Value(Model.DocumentId != null ? Model.RequestedDate : DateTime.Today)
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this way:

```
 @{ 
    dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
    if (Model.IsRequired)
    {
        obj.required = "required";
    }
    obj.style = "width:220px";
}
@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.Value)
        .Enable(!Model.IsDisabled)
        .Value(Model.DefaultValue)
        .HtmlAttributes(obj)
        .Name(Model.Name))
```